# Debugger doesn't launch in QtCreator 4.0.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: debugging

I am trying to debug a C++ application using QtCreator. When I debug that application, Debugger just hangs and says

*Starting debugger "GdbEngine" for ABI x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit"*

I tried attaching the debugger to a running process but debugger didn't attach.

`Debugger Logs:` https://pastebin.com/Pewcs721

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to fix debugging issue in QtCreator - I don't know what's wrong with that. Still looking for help. <br>
***Workaround:***<br>
I found the workaround, launch your program with gdbserver like this:
`gdbserver localhost:9999 ./<your program>`
and inside QtCreater
goto "Debug"->"Start Debugging"->"Attach to Running Debug Server" and press enter. 


Select your QtKit
Give server port, in this case: 9999
your server address is localhost: in this case.
select your executable
working directory.

Please "Ok" and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround 1:** Launch your program via command line and then goto QTCreater, attach the debugger to the running process. Debugger will attach to the running process.

**Workaround 2:** If you want to debug your program from start up, you can use gdbserver.

Launch your program with gdbserver like this: ***gdbserver localhost:9999 ./<"your program">*** and inside QtCreater goto **"Debug"->"Start Debugging"->"Attach to Running Debug Server"** and press enter. Select your QtKit, Give server port, in this case: 9999 your server address is localhost: in this case. select your executable working directory. Please "Ok" and you are good to go.